# SQL Server permission error after publishing website from visual studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1

Having all sorts of problems after publishing website from VS2015.

My Site has been working fine when run from within VS2015. However, I followed some instructions to Publish the website to my IIS and now the site Login page comes up but after entering user/password the application fails to make connection to the database and shows the error:

Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in impersonating the client. The connection will be closed.

I am running Windows 8.1, SQL Server 2008/R2, Visual Studio 2015 and the Database connect string is:

I do NOT currently have Database User I am simply connecting using Windows Integrated authentication.

I think it's some kind of permissions error, can someone please assist ?

Comment: Check the user under the app pool account in IIS. This is what will be used to connect to SQL server

Comment: Sorry check what? In IIS I can see Default Web Site assigned to DefaultApPool, can you provide more instructions, please?

Comment: look at this, you'll see some images that may help you to configure your app pool user: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: @moodhi The answer below by chief7 should get you what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website is using the AppPool identity to connect to the SQL database.  By default the AppPool uses a Built-in Account.

[image]

You can change the AppPool to use a custom domain account which as rights to the database.

Comment: After checking it was found that Identity is already set to ApplicationPoolIdentity which is not working. So I changed it LocalSystem and its all working now.  Why?

Comment: I assume the LocalSystem account has access to the database.

Comment: OK so how can I check LocalSystem account has access to the database while ApplicationPoolIdentity does NOT?

Comment: Don't have a ton of SQL experience but you would need to go to the security tab for the database in SQL Server Management Studio and review the accounts there and their rights.